# How to get the column which are not in inner join sql, using union all is time lot of time

Tags: sql, join, hive, apache-spark-sql, hql

I have 2 tables with same columns and have them inner join as below, I m trying to get the columns that are not taken in the inner join. I will be using this in a spark-sql code.

```
select A.pension, B.pension
from Db1.table1 A, Db2.table2 B
where to_date(A.rdt) = '2019-06-20' and A.state = 'ohio' and A.empno= B.empno;
```

I have tried using UNION ALL, but taking more time than system timeout, didnt add the clauses.

```
select A.pension
from Db1.table1 A left outer join
     Db2.table2 B 
     on A.pension = B.pension
where B.pension is null
UNION ALL
select B.pension
from Db2.table2 A left outer join
     Db1.table1 B 
     on A.pension = B.pension
where A.pension is null;
```

I have also tried using full outer join, taking time too, query didnt run.

```
select A.pension, B.pension
from Db1.table1 A full outer join
     Db2.table2 B
     on A.empno = B.empno
where to_date(A.rdt) = '2019-06-20' and A.state  = 'ohio' and A.pension = NULL or B.pension = NULL
```

rdt is in timestamp, pension int, empno int,

We just want the records which are not picked by the inner join, output must be a table with columns A.pension, B.pension, only has the records that are not matching in those two columns.

Answer (score 1):

`Full outer join` is tricky when using filtering.  I recommend doing the filtering in a subquery:

```
select A.pension, B.pension
from (select A.*
      from Db1.table1 A
      where to_date(A.rdt) = '2019-06-20' and A.state  = 'ohio' 
     ) A full outer join
     Db2.table2 B
     on A.empno = B.empno
where A.pension = NULL or B.pension = NULL
```

Comment: @vikrantrana . . . The result set should be the same, unless there is a bug in the Hive implementation.

Comment: Could have just used anti join to do the same.

Comment: anti join is not supported in spark-SQL. tried that one too. testing the above query with different scenarios, will update soon.

Comment: @gordonlinoff Hey, i tried using a table with data and without data, I am not able to get the result. The output is 0 results. I followed the same query, could this be because in one table the B.empno is not matching with A.empno

Comment: @sunk . . . Perhaps all rows match with those conditions on `table1`.

Comment: @gordonlinoff the second table has no data in it, just the schema. I have tried the condition of all the records matching too, by basically join same tables with different names.